# Why "document.title" and NOT "document.head.title"? RE: Traversing the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, properties

I am just beginning to learn client-side JavaScript and using an online tutorial, so please bear with me.

This question is based on my understanding of the following:

To access the properties of the document's body, the syntax is "document.body", which returns all the elements in the body.

Similarly when you access the head, you use "document.head". Makes sense and most importantly, it works.

However, when I attempt to access elements WITHIN the body or head following the same logic, I get a return value of "undefined". For example, document.body.h1, returns "undefined", in spite of there being an h1 element inside the body element.

Further, when I enter document.head.title -- "undefined".

Strangely, however, when I enter "document.title", it returns the string value associated with the title tag.

I thought in order to access the title, you would have to access it through the head, since it is an element nested inside the head. But ok, that's fine. Using the same logic, I should then be able to enter document.h1 and get its value.  Nope, instead, I get undefined.

Would someone be kind enough to explain to me why this behavior is so inconsistent.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `document.h1` this won't work neither `document.body.h1`... imagine that you are trying to get values from a `div`, how many divs your DOM can have? How document will know which one it needs to return?
to access elements from DOM, such as tags, you need to use selectors, such as `document.getElementById("IdYouWant")` or `document.querySelector("#idYouWant);` or even `document.getElementsByTagName("h1")`

Comment: its *grown historically*. `document.title` is a special API. Same is true for `document.body` and `document.head`. However from there you can use `children` to do DOM traversal (not that you *should do* that)

Comment: FYI, `document.body` does not return all the elements, it returns the `<body>` element

Comment: Thanks, lux.  Ok, that makes sense to me.  These are special cases.

Comment: If you search for `html document properties` you find which one is predefined... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document

Comment: LGSon, I don't believe I said it returns all the elements.  It "returns all the elements in the body."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've really asked two questions:

1. Why `document.title` rather than `document.head.title`?

and

2. Why doesn't `document.body.h1` return an element if there's an `h1` in the `body`?

#### `document.title`

`document.title` is historical. Various parts of the browser environment were developed somewhat ad hoc by multiple different people/organizations in the 1990s. :-) That said, it's the title of the document, so this isn't an unreasonable place to put it, even if you use the `title` tag in `head`.

#### `document.body.h1`

One answer is: Because no one decided to design it that way. There **were** some early things like `document.all` (a list of all elements in the document) and even tag-specific ones (I forget exactly what they were, but they weren't a million miles off your `document.body.h1` — I think `document.tags.h1` or something, where again it was a list.)

But another answer is: Because the DOM is a tree. `body` can have multiple `h1` elements, both as direct children and as children of children (or deeper); collectively, *descendants*. Creating automatic lists with all of these proved not to be scalable to large documents.

Instead, you can *query* the DOM (either the entire document, or just the contents of a specific element) via a variety of methods:

- [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) - (Just on `document`) Get an element using its `id` attribute value.
- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) - Find the first element matching a CSS selector (can use it on `document` or on an element). Returns `null` if there were no matches.
- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) - Get a *list* of all elements matching a CSS selector (can use it on `document` or on an element). You can rely on getting back a list; its `length` may be `0`, of course.
- [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) - Get a list of all elements with a given tag name (such as `"h1"`).
- [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) - (No support in IE8 and earlier) Get a list of all elements with a given class.

There are many more. See [MDN's web documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) and/or the [WHAT-WG DOM Standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/) for more.

Some of the automatic lists persist (they got so much use that they had to be maintained/kept), such as [`document.forms`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-forms), [`document.links`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-links), the [`rows`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-table-rows) property on [`HTMLTableElement`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#htmltableelement) and [`HTMLTableSectionElement`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#htmltablesectionelement) instances, the [`cells`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-tr-cells) property on [`HTMLTableRowElement`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#htmltablerowelement) instances, and various others.

Comment: Thanks, TJ, for taking the time to respond.  This is very helpful.  All the best --

Comment: @Luca: No, there were ones for all tags, I think as a subproperty of something. (I mention those ones above, at the end of the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

`document.head.title` is a thing... but not what you might think.

[title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title) is an attribute that is applicable to **all** html elements; that is, it is a [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes). It's meaning is 'advisory information'; one use is to display a tooltip:

```
<span title="hover over me and you'll see this">information</span>
```

So, all elements have a title attribute - including [head](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head). The [title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title) *element* - which is completely different - should be a child of the head though. So you might be tempted to set its value via `document.head.title = "my title"` , but `document.head.title` is **not** the head's title element, it's a *property* of the head element.

What you're actually doing is setting the title property on the head element:

```
<head title="my title">.... </head>
```

... which isn't what you want at all.

The correct way to set the title is `document.title`, which is a shortcut way of doing

```
document.querySelector("title").innerText = "my title"
```